# Need help trying to test function to find area of rectangle using co-ordinates

Tags: python, function, testing, area

I have a Rectangle class that finds the area of a Rectangle using top-left and bottom-right coordinates. I'm having trouble writing up a test function to test the code and verify it works.

```
class Rectangle: # rectangle class
    # make rectangle using top left and bottom right coordinates
    def __init__(self,tl,br):
        self.tl=tl
        self.br=br
        self.width=abs(tl.x-br.x)  # width
        self.height=abs(tl.y-br.y) # height
    def area(self):
        return self.width*self.height
```

So far I have written this which leads to an AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'

```
def test_rectangle():
    print("Testing rectangle class")
    rect = Rectangle((3,10),(4,8))
    actual = rect.area()
    print("Result is %d" % actual)
```

What can I change to the code in order to make it work?

Comment: Looks like tl and br are tuples that do not have an x attribute. Can you do `tl[0]` and `tl[1]` instead ?

Comment: Thanks, @Fabich that's sorted out the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Rectangle: # rectangle class
    # make rectangle using top left and bottom right coordinates
    def __init__(self,tl,br):
        self.tl=tl
        self.br=br
        self.width=abs(tl[0]-br[0])  # width
        self.height=abs(tl[1]-br[1]) # height
    def area(self):
        return self.width*self.height
```

If with `x` and `y` you mean the first and second elements of your tuples `tl` and `br` you should use indexes instead. Tuples have no such attributes.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to define `tl` and `br` as dictionaries instead of objects. Here is an example.

```py
class Rectangle:  # rectangle class
    """Make rectangle using top left and bottom right coordinates."""
    def __init__(self, tl, br):
        self.width = abs(tl["x"] - br["x"])
        self.height = abs(tl["y"] - br["y"])

    def area(self):
        return self.width * self.height


def test_rectangle():
    print("Testing rectangle class")
    tl = {"x": 3, "y": 10}
    br = {"x": 4, "y": 8}
    rect = Rectangle(tl, br)
    actual = rect.area()
    print("Result is %d" % actual)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_rectangle()
```